# Interactions between a form and a modal form

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I need to help the user to fill a set of fields in a content type form, this way :

The users start to fill one of the concerned fields: They click on a button that will open a modal form. The modal form will propose some choices depending on the filled fields; when users choose a proposition, the modal form closes and the fields of the original form get updated with the chosen proposition.

I have tested 2 methods to open the modal form and I have issues with both.

With the first method, I can open and close the modal form, but I can't transmit field values from the form 1 to the modal form; with the second method, I can pass the field values to the modal form, but I fail closing this modal form.

How can I update the fields from the first form when I close the modal form?

This is my .module file. Read the comments for details.

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenModalDialogCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CloseModalDialogCommand;


/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_test_module_form_node_article_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)  {

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

    $form['my_fieldset'] = array (
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#title' => t ( 'My fieldset' ),
            '#collapsible' => TRUE,
            '#collapsed' => FALSE,
            '#tree' => TRUE
    );
    $form['my_fieldset']['my_field_1'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Field 1'),
    );
    $form['my_fieldset']['my_field_2'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Field 2'),
    );
    // METHOD 1
    // Problem : it doesn't allow to transmit my field values (from the $form_state) to the modal Form
    $form['my_fieldset']['open_modal1'] = array(
            '#type' => 'link',
            '#title' => t('Open modal 1'),
            '#url' => Url::fromRoute('my_test_module.modal_form'),
            '#attributes' => array(
                    'class' => array('button', 'use-ajax'),
                    'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
            ),
    );
    // METHOD 2
    // Problem : The modal form can't be closed
    $form['my_fieldset']['open_modal2'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Open modal 2'),
            '#ajax' => array(
                    'callback' =>  'my_test_module_open_modal_form',
                    'event' => 'click',
            ),
    );
}

/**
 * Ajax Callback for the form - it opens the modal form
 *
 */
function my_test_module_open_modal_form($form, $form_state) {

    $values = $form_state->getValues(); 

    // Get the modal form
    $modal_form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\my_test_module\Form\MyModalForm',$values['my_fieldset']['my_field_1'],$values['my_fieldset']['my_field_2']);
    // Add an AJAX command to open a modal dialog with the form as the content.
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand(t('My Modal'), $modal_form, ['width' => '555']));  
    return $response;
}
```

The modal form class I use is the following one.

```
/**
* @file
* Contains \Drupal\my_test_module\Form\MyModalForm.
*/

namespace Drupal\my_test_module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CloseModalDialogCommand;

/**
 * This class restitutes the modal form
 *
 */
class MyModalForm extends FormBase {

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'MyModalForm';
    }

    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $field_1 = NULL, $field_2 = NULL) {

        $form['m1'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'Field 1 : ' . $field_1,
        );
        $form['m2'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'Field 2 : ' . $field_2,
        );

        $form['results'] = array (
                '#type' => 'table',
                '#header' => array('Field 1', 'Field 2',''),
        );


        $form['results'][0]['field_1'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'AAAA',
        );
        $form['results'][0]['field_2'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'BBBB',
        );
        $form['results'][0]['submit0'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => 'Choose',
                'name' => '0',
                '#attributes' => [
                        'class' => [
                                'use-ajax',
                        ],
                ],
                '#ajax' => array(
                        'callback' => '::ajaxCloseModal',
                        'event' => 'click',
                ),
        );

        $form['results'][1]['field_1'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'AAAA',
        );
        $form['results'][1]['field_2'] = array(
                '#markup' => 'BBBB',
        );
        $form['results'][1]['submit1'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => 'Choose',
                'name' => '1',
                '#attributes' => [
                        'class' => [
                                'use-ajax',
                        ],
                ],
                '#ajax' => array(
                        'callback' => '::ajaxCloseModal',
                        'event' => 'click',
                ),
        );
        return $form;

    }

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    }

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    }

    public function ajaxCloseModal(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());
        //Get the triggering element, then replace the field_1 and field_2 values in the original form
        return $response;

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

For closing model form you can use jquery. When field value will update javascript change event will occur so you can trigger modal form close button or link

```
$( "#textField" ).change(function() {
  $( "#close" ).trigger( "click" ); // if modal form have close button or some url
  $( "#modal" ).modal( "toggle" ); // in case of using bootstrap modal form
});
```

References: [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: I would like to avoid using jquery at this point when I'm not far from a full Drupal solution. But that will be an option if I don't find other solution. Thanks.